# ON DELETE / ON UPDATE doubts

Tags: update, foreign-key, delete, syntax, cascade

I was looking at database past exam from the school that I attend, and I have a question about ON DELETE and ON UPDATE.

The question in the past exam was:

> Show the contents of the tables after the insturction `update Student set sid=1234 where sid=4563` If `on delete cascade` was used on the reference from Enrollment to Student.

(Enrollment has an attribute referencing to the student relation)

So if `on delete cascade` was used, and if we were to update the student relation wouldn't this be rejected since it was `on delete cascade`, not `on update cascade`?

Comment: You MUST show full DDLs. And you MUST specify ONE DBMS - either SQL Server or MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

> if we were to update student relation wouldn't this be rejected

This is correct. If there is no `ON UPDATE` action defined in the `foreign key` reference,
your `update` of `referenced key` would coflict with the `foreign key constaint` so it would be rejected.